# Wrap ASP.Net Repeater around an image only ONCE

Tags: asp.net, repeater

I've searched for an answer to this for days with no joy, and am confident I'll get a solution here.

In brief...

I have an asp:Repeater, and it is working beautifully, populating from the code-behind.  The page, however, is very plain looking, and the owner wants to put an image in the upper right corner.  Sounds simple enough.

Wrapping text around an image is something I can do.
Populating a repeater is also something I can do.

What I can't seem to figure out is how to wrap the text around a single image IN the repeater.

=======
Other options?

The idea here is, these are comments and tips from a soccer coach to his team.  They are usually one short paragraph with a date and title.  They will display for 90 days and then drop off.

Is there something better than a repeater to use for this?  It seemed like the best way to go, but I'm a novice with C# and asp.Net.

Comment: So you want the image only once on the page, regardless of how many records there are, is that right?

Comment: Just one image in the upper right? Or an image per item in the repeater?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a single image for the entire repeater, put an image control in the HeaderTemplate, like so:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <asp:Image ID="imgSingle" />
    </HeaderTemplate>...
```

If you want an image for each comment/tip, put the image control in the ItemTemplate, like so:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Image ID="imgMultiple" runat="server" />
    </ItemTemplate>
```

Is this what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: My apologies to the community.  I have been away, and just now got back to this project.  I think I may need to look at my profile settings and see if there is an option to be emailed when responses are posted.  

I see multiple responses and some questions.  For clarification, the soccer coach (my son) wants to define an image for each comment in the repeater.  I will try the second approach mentioned by Shai Cohen above and see if it produces the desired result.  I've put new fields in his DB to allow him to define/upload individual images and link each one so a specific coaching tip.

Comment: Progress made in that a distinct image is displaying with each coaching tip, but the text is not wrapping the image. I'm going to try to insert a code block here, but as I'm new to the forum I may just make a mess.

Yup, just made a mess.  So, I don't tag to make a code block?  Just a four space indent??

Comment: Still learning this forum.  I see I was to address my comments to you with the "at" symbol.  Still cannot seem to embed code blocks.  Would like to show you how I implemented your solution and see if you note why my text isn't wrapping.

Comment: Don't worry, you will figure out SO soon enough :). The best way is probably to update your answer with new code/questions. Or, if the question is a completely new subject, just create a new one.

Answer (score 1):

The repeater doesn't produce a containing HTML element in itself, so you can put the image outside the repeater, but still inside the element containing the list.

Example:

```
<div>

  <img src="..." style="float:right" />

  <asp:Repeader ... >

</div>
```

The content in the repeater will flow around the image, inside the containing div.

Comment: Option 2: put the image in the header template. This way the image only shows if the repeater's data source actually returns data.